# После попытки переустановить Nginx - не работает терминал в Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

Я скорее всего идиот. Выполнил вот эту инструкцию: http://catethysis.ru/nginx-full-reinstall/ и теперь у меня в Ubuntu 14.04 изменилось визуальное оформление. Но это не самое страшное. Самое страшное, что вместо терминала теперь черный квадрат. Не отображается ничего.

Для тех, кто не захочет переходить по ссылке - вот что написано в инструкции:

```
#удаляем nginx и все связанные пакеты
sudo apt-get remove nginx*

#удаляем рабочие директории и логи
sudo rm -rf /etc/nginx/ /usr/sbin/nginx /usr/share/man/man1/nginx.1.gz

#удаляем остатки nginx из базы apt
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove nginx && sudo dpkg --purge nginx

#устанавливаем nginx заново с чистыми конфигами
sudo apt-get -o DPkg::options::=--force-confmiss --reinstall install nginx
```

Система попросила скачать обновления после команды `sudo apt-get --purge autoremove`, я по привычка нажал скачать. И после перезагрузки - черный квадрат вместо терминала. Сижу плачу...

Из того, что я еще сделал ранее, возможно это важно: случайно добавил доверенный репозиторий nginx для ubuntu 14.10 у меня 14.04. Т.е. вместо:

```
deb http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu/ trusty nginx
deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu/ trusty nginx
```

добавил:

```
deb http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu/ utopic nginx
deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu/ utopic nginx
```

Выполнил команду `sudo apt-get update`. Затем понял свою ошибку, изменил репозиторий на правильный и снова выполнил команду `sudo apt-get update`

Google на тему черный терминал ничего не дает. Помогите.

Comment: Есть ли смысл оставлять этот вопрос? Решение нашел в том, что изменил тему на контрастную. Почему-то моя система посчитала, что я не использую визуальную оболочку и удалила ее командой autoremove. Может, флаг --purge на это намекнул, фиг знает.

Comment: Не знаю досконально всех команд, но не вижу ничего криминального, что могло бы так повлиять. Попробуйте нажать alt + ctrl + f1, это включит tty1 (привычный десктоп возвращается по alt + ctrl + f7)

Comment: Не совсем понятно в каком именно месте поломался гуй. Можно скриншот как оно сейчас показывается?

Comment: Уже починил. Написал же. Показывает плохо. Полностью весь внешний вид удалился. Теперь не знаю, как заново вернуть красивую оболочку ubuntu (

Comment: посмотрите  логи что вы там наудаляли: `/var/log/apt/`

Comment: Да, посмотрел. Удалил кучу библиотек, так понимаю, отвечающих за визуальное оформление (названия начинаются на lib*)